# Apply custom spans to args defined in a string resource

Tags: java, android, string, android-resources, spannablestring

I have strings resources defined like:

```
<string name="follow">%1$s and %2$s are following you</string>
```

and I retrieve them using `Resources.getString(int stringId, Object... formatArgs)` as follows:

```
res.getString(R.string.follow, user1.name(), user2.name());
```

Now I want to apply some text span only to the usernames. I know that some spans can be defined directly in XML and later retrieved using `Html.fromHtml()`, however these are my own span classes which are clearly not supported by `Html`.

How can I do that?

The only solution that comes to my mind is using some special char in the original string, like

```
<string name="follow">*%1$s* and *%2$s* are following you</string>
```

however I'm having issues also with this solution and it would break if one of the usernames has some `*` in it (just an example).

Comment: see `Spannable` interface

Comment: @pskink not sure I got you - I know how to set spans, I just don't know the start and end indices of the usernames in the retrieved string, so I can't use setSpan()

Comment: I tried passing SpannableStrings to the formatArgs but these are not keeped by getString().

Comment: then search for `%1$`, `%2$` etc and `setSpan`s around them